# Error #1250 - Table 'x' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause

Tags: mysql

I ran this query through an optimizer.

```
SELECT *, chv_images.image_id FROM chv_images
LEFT JOIN chv_storages ON chv_images.image_storage_id = chv_storages.storage_id
LEFT JOIN chv_users ON chv_images.image_user_id = chv_users.user_id
LEFT JOIN chv_albums ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id
LEFT JOIN chv_categories ON chv_images.image_category_id = chv_categories.category_id
LEFT JOIN chv_meta ON chv_images.image_id = chv_meta.image_id
WHERE chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 AND (chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private','private_but_link','custom') OR chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL OR chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL)
ORDER BY chv_images.image_id DESC
LIMIT 0,15
```

It came out looking like this, definitely better in theory from what I understand.

```
(
        SELECT
            *,
            chv_images.image_id 
        FROM
            chv_images 
        LEFT JOIN
            chv_albums 
                ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id 
        WHERE
            chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 
            AND (
                chv_albums.album_user_id IS NULL
            ) 
        ORDER BY
            chv_images.image_id DESC LIMIT 0,
            15
    ) 
UNION
DISTINCT (SELECT
    *,
    chv_images.image_id 
FROM
    chv_images 
LEFT JOIN
    chv_albums 
        ON chv_images.image_album_id = chv_albums.album_id 
WHERE
    chv_images.image_nsfw = 0 
    AND (chv_albums.album_privacy NOT IN ('private', 'private_but_link', 'custom') 
    OR chv_albums.album_privacy IS NULL) 
ORDER BY
    chv_images.image_id DESC LIMIT 0,
    15) 
ORDER BY
chv_images.image_id DESC LIMIT 0,
15
```

But there's one problem. Error #1250 - Table 'chv_images' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in global ORDER clause.

I tried removing some of the parentheses but that didn't work.

Comment: Remove the table alias in the last ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Like this? "ORDER BY image_id DESC LIMIT 0, 15"

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thanks. see comment.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I removed the entire final order by clause and it looks to be working.

Comment: I guess after you've removed the table alias you have got the next error like `column image_id is ambiguous`. This is because you use `SELECT *, chv_images.image_id`. The column `image_id` occurs three times in the result. Just list all the columns you need in the SELECT clause. Don't use `*`. Then you'll be able to add the ORDER BY clause again.