# #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns problem

Tags: mysql, select, union

I want to select orders and products from different table to draw a bar chart but it show me error in this query, I tried much but I don't know what is the problem please help.

```
SELECT *,count(products.id) as no_products FROM products GROUP BY
MONTH(products.added_on) , YEAR(products.added_on) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT *,count(orders.id) as no_orders FROM orders GROUP BY 
MONTH(orders.added_on) , YEAR(orders.added_on)  order by 
YEAR(orders.added_on) asc, MONTH(orders.added_on) asc
```

Comment: Both sides of the `union` need an identical number of columns. Stop using `*` and manually list all the columns you need.

Comment: @Martin I replaced it but now this error comes #1250 - Table 'orders' from one of the SELECTs cannot be used in ORDER clause

Comment: Research this error yourself and you will find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48836846/error-1250-table-x-from-one-of-the-selects-cannot-be-used-in-global-order-c